# Difference between squares of lattice points on a circle. Is this truly impossible?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, trigonometry, circles, integers, integer-lattices

### Introduction

[image: Five right-angled triangles with same diagonal length representing lattice points on a circle]
Above are five triangles that all have the same value **r** and thus **B**, **E**, **H**, **K**, and **N** are all points on a circle with radius **r**. Triangle **ABC** is a right angled isosceles triangle.

All triangles are different and ordered descending such that:
$$a>b>c>d>e>0$$

In this case we are only interested in lattice points.
**a**, **b**, **c**, **d**, and **e** are all odd numbers.
**a** in specific is of form (4k+1), because adding gaussian primes factors (4k+3) will only multiply every other value by the same amount.

$$r= \sqrt{2}\cdot a$$
$$a= (4k+1)$$
$$a,b,c,d,e,k\in\mathbb Z$$

### Problem

Given the above information, prove that any (or a combination) of the following is impossible:

1. $a^2+d^2=b^2+c^2$
2. $c^2+e^2=2d^2$
3. $a^2+e^2=b^2+d^2$

It can be proven by showing that:

- This cannot be done with integers;
- This can only be done with irrational numbers;
- Some trigonometry or number theory fact proving this impossible.

### Solving attempts so far

I have tried numerous ways of calculus and trigonometry of solving this, but I always seem to be one piece of information or fact short. Furthermore I have set up some coding to check is solution for the main problem can be found. At time of writing the program has checked values up to r = 5.2*10^13.

I hope this problem proves plenty of challenge for you. May you be able to solve I will be greatly thankful!

Comment: Please clarify the expression for $r$ : Is it $\sqrt{2}\cdot (4k+1)^2$ ?

Comment: No, it is: r = sqrt( 2*(4k+1)² ), because a = (4k+1). Thus: a² + a² = r²

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.  For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on MathJax notation](/help/notation), [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/259305) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189).

Comment: Why then not just "$\sqrt{2}\cdot (4k+1)$" ?

Comment: Sorry, I misread. You are correct.

Comment: (1) and (3) seem to be the same statement with different letters; indeed, (2) is also a special case of this statement if we allow one nonstrict inequality instead of $a>b>c>d>e$.

Comment: @GregMartin, (1) and (3) are different statements giving insight in the relation between triangles that I am looking for. If one of those, or all those formulas combined are proven impossible than the problem truly is impossible. I do not understand your remark about (2) and nonstrict inequality. Just to be sure: the difference between ab, bc, cd, and de can all be different.

Comment: 13th version of the question.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson, if there are similar questions by other I would like to know. Haven't found them myself yet.

Comment: What I mean is, this question has been edited and edited and edited and we're now up to the 13th edition of it. Every edit bounces it back up to the front page, bouncing some newer question off. Also, makes the question something of a moving target. Who would post an answer, knowing the question hasn't settled down yet and could change without notice at any minute?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson, ok I understand now. I edited it too make it more clear. Should be clear now and will require no further edits.